# Opencv 300 - Random Forest Predict returns wrong answer

Tags: c++, opencv, random-forest, opencv3.0, predict

Do you guys have any idea about what is wrong with the following simple Random Forest example in OpenCV 300  (It always predict "0" which is wrong):

```
Mat train_data= (Mat_<int>(6,3) << 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, -1, -1, -1, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, -1, -2, -3);
Mat response = (Mat_<int>(1,6) << 0,0,0,1, 1, 1);

Ptr<TrainData> tdata = TrainData::create(train_data, ROW_SAMPLE, response);

Ptr<RTrees> model;
    model = RTrees::create();
    model->setMaxDepth(4);
    model->setMinSampleCount(5);
    model->setRegressionAccuracy(0);
    model->setUseSurrogates(false);
    model->setMaxCategories(15);
    model->setPriors(Mat());
    model->setCalculateVarImportance(true);
    model->setActiveVarCount(4);
    model->setTermCriteria(TC(100,0.01f));
    model->train(tdata);

Mat sample;
sample = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << 0,0,0);  // if I use <int> I'll get error
cout << model->predict(sample) <<"\n";

sample = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << -4,-5,-6);
cout << model->predict(sample) <<"\n";

sample = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << 9,9,9);
cout << model->predict(sample) <<"\n";

sample = (Mat_<float>(1,3) << 19,20,21);
cout << model->predict(sample) <<"\n";
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I know I might be a bit late, but I had the same problem with OpenCV 2.4.13 and it seems that OpenCV's RandomTrees algorithm doesn't like classes with value 0,

I mean if one or more elements of your **response** Matrice is/are 0, the RTree algorithm will always predict 0.

I solved it by replacing all the 0 in **response** Matrice by another value (e.g. 2 in your case will be ok).